# Can we study concavity of vorticity equation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, numerical-analysis-of-pde, navier-stokes

The vorticity equation is well known given as

\begin{equation}\label{Eq1}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\textbf{v} + (\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla )\textbf{v} - (\textbf{v}\cdot \nabla )\textbf{u} = \nu \bigtriangleup\textbf{v}, ~~~~~~~ \textbf{v}: = \textbf{curl}(\textbf{u}(x,t))\tag{15}
\end{equation}

with initial condition

\begin{equation}\label{Eq2}
\textbf{v}(x,0) = \textbf{curl}(\textbf{u}(x,0)):= \xi(x) .
\end{equation}

which is to be solved for the vector field $\textbf{v}(x,t)$ as time progresses. What can we say about the critical points of $\textbf{v}$?

Comment: The title of the question asks about concavity; the body about critical points. In either case the question seems rather broad and vague. What kind of results are you looking for? And how does this come up in your research?

Comment: @MaxHorn I'm trying to study the behavior or the vorticity equation.  In 1 dimension the critical points of function are when the derivative is zero.  I came up with it using Helmholtz theorem to write the non-linear component. You can see that unusually long post here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459451/stokes-equation-and-helmholtz-decomposition

Comment: @MaxHorn If I can bound vorticity then I can bound the solution because it would be a function of its curl and I already found the irrotational part or curl free part